# YouTube api always gives the same videos for different queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

I'm making a site that loads videos from YouTube. The problem is that I always get the same videos when I use an other query. If I use the queries below the result is the same in both situations.

1. With 'plop'

   ```
   https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&key=my_key&q=plop
   ```

   [image: Whit plop]
2. With 'K3':

   ```
   https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&key=my_key&q=k3
   ```

   [image: Whit K3]

Here is my code:

```js
$("body").ready(function () {
    init();
});

function init() {
    $("#search-button").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&key=my_key&q=" + $("#query"),
            success: function (data) {

                //data = JSON.parse(data);
                var lengte = data.items.length;

                $("#search-container").empty();

                for(var i = 0; i < lengte; i++) {

                    $("#search-container").append('<iframe width="427" height="240" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + data.items[i].id.videoId + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
                }
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log("oops");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttons">
    <label>
        <input id="query" type="text"/>
        <button id="search-button" >Search</button>
    </label>
</div>
<div id="search-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the URL you are sending should be:

```
 url: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&key=my_key&q=" + $("#query").val(),
```

Currently it seems you are trying to append the `input` element, so youtube is searching for 'object' , as you can see from the results. To fix this, you have to add `.val()` to get the value in the textbox.

Hope this helps!